# How to 'skip' specific words using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am writing a program which takes the explanation of a German idiom from Wikipedia, for example, and catches the idiom, its meaning and any additional information.

Example, the bolded text is supposed to be matched:

> ** Sich wie ein Backfisch benehmen – **albern bzw. unreif sein**. Zur Etymologie des Wortes „Backfisch“ für unreife Mädchen siehe dort. (Sprichwort um 1900: „Mit 14 Jahr’n und sieben Wochen ist der Backfisch ausgekrochen.“[6]).

Basically, the phrase starts after the dash **-** and ends before the first full stop, i.e. it is only one sentence. **However, i want to skip abbreviations such as *bzw.*, *z. B.*, *u. A.*,** etc, since they do not mark the end of the sentence.

I am unsure how to skip the word, but still match it. Also, as I said, I want to skip frequently used abbreviations in German such as the aforementioned ones in italics.

I already tried matching a structure beginning with **-** and ending with **.**, whereas the **.** should not be preceded by *bzw*. However, I did not succeed in doing that.

Comment: How would one determine what is an abbreviation or not?

Comment: "since they do not mark the end of the sentence" - do they *never* mark the end of a sentence?

Comment: @iakobski no they don't, it's the same as in English, where _i.e._ or _e.g._ would never be the last word in a sentence.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness This is a trivial answer, but I just do, because I know German. I am not using any programming logic for that.

Comment: You can't parse English, German, French or any language with regex. It is utterly impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a **non-capturing group**. Take a look:

```
(?<=– )(?:.+)?(?:bzw\.|Z\. b\.|u\. a\.)[^\.]+
```

[image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P7aonE/6) - top right you can see description of individual regex components.

```
(?<=– )                    start after – character + whitespace, but not match
(?:.+)?                    add any text before abbreviation into non-capturing group.
(?:bzw\.|Z\. b\.|u\. a\.)  add abbreviations into non-capturing group. Escape the dots via \. 
[^\.]+                     match anything until fullstop
```

Essentially the idea is to start with the – character + whitespace, but not match it. Then capture any following text, abbreviation and capture till the first dot `.`, but without capturing the abbreviations group (notice the `?:`). Since the abbreviation dot is part of the non-capturing group, we "skip" it and continue until the dot that ends the sentence. You can expand the abbreviations list by adding more abbreviations via the `|` symbol.

**Bonus:**

If you are anticipating that you will not always start with the `–` sequence, you can do the following:

```
(?:– |: )((?:.+)?(?:bzw\.|Z\. b\.|u\. a\.)[^\.]+)
```

This will allow the regex to work also with `:` character instead of `–`, for example, but you will need to retrieve the result as group 1.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P7aonE/7)

Comment: Thank you! To further complicate the situation, let's say the sentence is "albern _oder_ unreif sein" (replaced the _bzw._ with _oder_). I tried modifying the regex, so that it captures the sentence, but did not succeed, is it possible to do that?

Comment: @Daka sure, just add oder using | -> ...(?:oder|bzw\.|Z\. b\.|u\. a\.)... https://regex101.com/r/9BrekC/1

Answer (score 1):

That is a problem in German, using abbreviations, I encountered it when working on German texts, too. Did you try to use a German parser, in order to cut your text in phrases/sentences ? Try one, it may help. In Python you have NLTK and also Stanford, for example.

In English or French one may say that the end of a phrase is marked by a point followed by space and a capital letter. However this will not work for German, as the Nouns are capitalized.

On the other hand, as you mention "frequently used abbreviations" -- if they are so frequent, why not collecting them in a dictionary and use them in order to skip them in the text ?

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I tried using NLTK package and tokenizing the text and thereby splitting it into sentences. However, the tokenizer falsely recognises the **.** after _bzw_ as the end of the sentence.

Comment: Try Stanford parser too.